# Pointers in typedef structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

I have the code:

```
typedef struct foo *bar;

struct foo {
    int stuff
    char moreStuff;
}
```

Why does the following give an `incompatible pointer type` error?

```
foo Foo;
bar Bar = &Foo;
```

To my knowledge, `bar` should be defined as a pointer to `foo`, no?

Comment: You have no type `foo` in your examlple, so `foo Foo` shouldn't compile. You are also missing a semicolin in your `struct` definition. Would you care to post code that really reproduces the error you ask for help you about?

Comment: Oh, I'm very dumb. I wanted to make a type from my struct, fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete code should look like

```
typedef struct foo *bar;

typedef struct foo {  //notice the change
    int stuff;
    char moreStuff;
}foo;
```

and the usage

```
foo Foo;
bar Bar = &Foo;
```

Without having the typedef in `struct foo`, you code won't compile.

Also, mind the `;` after struct definition [and after `int stuff` *also*, though I assume that's more of a *typo*].

Comment: @AlterMann Absolutely. Missed that one. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should be:

```
typedef struct foo *bar;

struct foo {
    int stuff;
    char moreStuff;
};


int main()
{
  struct foo Foo;
  bar Bar = &Foo;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the code like this.

```
typedef struct foo *bar;

struct foo {
  int stuff;
  char moreStuff;
};

struct foo Foo;
bar Bar = &Foo;
```

Or else you can use the typedef for that structure.

```
typedef struct foo {
  int stuff;
  char moreStuff;
}foo;

foo Foo;
bar Bar=&Foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this code is very obfuscated/ cluttered with unnecessary, undesirable elements.

In all cases, code should be written to be clear to the human reader.
this includes:
-- not making instances of objects by just changing the capitalization.
-- not renaming objects for no purpose

suggest:

struct foo 
{
    int stuff;
    char moreStuff;
};

struct foo   myFoo;
struct foo * pMyFoo = &myFoo;

which, amongst other things, actually compiles
```